# Security issues in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When calling the AJAX call, the call request and response can see on console by using the firebug. This is major security issue. How can we hide the response(data) from the console?

Is there any option?

Comment: There's no way of hiding it from the console unless you also make it unusable from your code.  If you're concerned about sending data back to the client then I'd question what you're sending.  You should only ever transport data that you're happy to give out to the end user.

Comment: I don't understand your question, Ajax is like any request response on the web

Comment: @Archer yes ur right Iam happy to give out to end user, but I need to hide some data in response thats y I asking

Comment: @Kandhi if the data is in any way encrypted so that the client cannot read it then it would be useless.  The only way to read it would be to decrypt it, but then the user would be able to use your own code to decrypt anything you send back, so it would become pointless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that the data is arrived in the client means client has the authority to read and do whatever it wants with it. Now if that data is a security risk, then it should never be sent to the client in the first place.

If you are worried that someone other than the client might see it then use HTTPS.

If you are worried that people can see it in the firebug, well then that data is not supposed to be seen by client. **Hiding firebug is only making it harder, not impossible.** You may always use Fiddler to see HTTP content or even wireshark to see the packets.

Comment: @ Aliostad I am fresher in this field thats y asking this. thanks for ur quick responce

Answer (score 1):

You can never really hide something you send to the client, if you want to handle sensitive operations you should do so on a server you control.

Not knowing what it is you want to do, this is about what i can tell you...

Answer (score 0):

If you're not concerned by the end user seing the data but someone "in the middle" then maybe you should use **https**